# Extracting data from database onto a text field on android studio

Tags: java, php, sql

I have an app, and what I'm trying to do, is extract a single piece of data into a text field. For example:

[image: Image of the text field of app]

In that image, I have a label called tariff, and adjacent to it, I have a textview field. I want to be able to draw the tariff name from my database into that field.

I've looked at all other tutorials and they usually involve a button, that has to be clicked on in order for data from the database to be extracted.

**Note: Prior to arriving at this activity of the app, a user must log into the app, a user is associated to a tariff name. I basically want to upload a tariff name based on the username onto textviewt**.

I hope that makes sense. Please do let me know if you have any further questions regarding this.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand what I need to do to achieve this.

Thanks in advance to those who have read the post!

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer data between activities by passing an Intent to the startActivity(Intent) method. In your case the Intent would contain the username that was passed in by the user and with that username you can upload the tariff name.

You can use the onCreate() method if you need to get data from the database without the user clicking on a button.

Comment: Ah i see. So would i do something like this: Intent intent = new Intent(this, Page.class); intent.putExtra('username', getUsername);  Then in second activity you retrive argument like this:      EditText username = getIntent().getExtras() - would it be something like that? Apologies if its incorrect, im quite new to android studio

Comment: It's not exactly what you would do but it is in broad terms.